# Convert CamelCaseText to CamelCaseNamingStrategy in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I recently upgraded to the latest `Newtonsoft.Json` version `12.0.2`. I was previously running an older version (`11.0.2`), and somewhere in between, the `StringEnumConverter.CamelCaseText` property was deprecated.

Per the [StringEnumConverter class](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs), `"StringEnumConverter.CamelCaseText is obsolete. Set StringEnumConverter.NamingStrategy with CamelCaseNamingStrategy instead."` As a result, I made the following change in scenarios where `CamelCaseText == true`:

```
// Deprecated approach
new StringEnumConverter() { CamelCaseText = true };

// New approach
new StringEnumConverter() { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() };
```

While this seems straightforward, I am unsure how to approach scenarios where `CamelCaseText == false`. I have read the [CamelCaseNamingStrategy class](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCaseNamingStrategy.cs) but do not know where I would disable the camel-casing. My guess is that I need to use a different naming strategy class than `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` such as [`DefaultNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultNamingStrategy.htm), but I am unsure what the difference is in the behavior of this class.

Can anybody point me to documentation explaining the difference, and/or help me understand which naming strategy to use in this case?

```
// Deprecated approach
new StringEnumConverter() { CamelCaseText = false };

// New approach
new StringEnumConverter() { NamingStrategy = ? };
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace it with the NamingStrategy, use following code instead:

```
new StringEnumConverter { NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy() };
```

Other alternatives are:
`CamelCaseNamingStrategy` , `KebabCaseNamingStrategy` , `SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`

Answer (score 3):

You can just do `new StringEnumConverter()` without modifying any properties.

By default, `StringEnumConverter` does not transform the `enum` names in any way.  This is explained in the docs for the obsolete [`StringEnumConverter.CamelCaseText`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter_CamelCaseText.htm) which state:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the written enum text should be camel case. **The default value is `false`**.

If you feel a need to set the value of [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter_NamingStrategy.htm) you can set it to `null` (the [default value](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs#L85)), or [`new DefaultNamingStrategy()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultNamingStrategy.htm).  Either choice will cause `StringEnumConverter` to not modify `enum` names.